# Exercises to go with Simon's "Representations of finite and compact groups"

Tags: reference-request, exercises

I am teaching an independent-reading course from Simon's "Representations of finite and compact groups".  I chose this book based on fond memories from a previous reading course in which I had participated as assistant, but then discovered that it has no exercises.  At least for the early material, I'm not finding it easy to create relevant exercises myself.

**What books, or online resources for other courses, have relevant exercises for this book?**

Obviously it's best if they are specifically intended as companions to Simon's book, but I am interested in exercises for other first courses in representation theory as well.  The book's point of view is intended to lead up to the representation theory of compact Lie groups.  More specifically, the table of contents is available at http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=GSM-10.  (The first 3 chapters listed there are spurious, and appear to be a typo.)

Comment: you might like to get a copy of Steinberg's representation theory book: http://www.amazon.com/Representation-Theory-Finite-Groups-Introductory/dp/1461407753/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1409455547&sr=8-4&keywords=group+representation my brother used this with undergraduates and it worked well.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook, thanks!  I have just got it off SpringerLink, and will have a look.

Comment: Not tied to your book, but Karen Smith taught a very successful homework-heavy rep theory course. Her problem sets can be found at http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/REP.html

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, thanks!  Karen is a great teacher, so I am confident that her homework sets will have much to offer.